# Skip a column when using a for loop

Tags: r, plot

I am creating a function that automatically creates histograms in a matrix.  However, if one of the columns in the matrix is not an integer or numeric the function stops and does not continue to complete the rest of the columns. Below is the code

```
V1 <- rnorm(26)
V2<-letters
V3 <- rnorm(26)
all.data <- matrix(V1, V2, V3)
My_function <- function(x)
  for(i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    hist(x[,i], main = paste("Histogram of",colnames(x)[i]), xlab=paste(colnames(x)[i]))
  }
My_function(all.data)
```

I need to know what to add to my code to tell R to skip columns that are not integer/numeric (such as V2 in my example) so that I get all the histograms I want and skip the non integer/numeric columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would be to actually get the class and then index numeric only

```
V1 <- rnorm(26)
V2<-letters
V3 <- rnorm(26)
all.data <- data.frame(V1, V2, V3)
My_function <- function(x){
  col<-which(sapply(x,class) %in% c("numeric","integer"))
             for(i in col) {
               hist(x[,i], main = paste("Histogram of",colnames(x)    [i]),    
                    xlab=paste(colnames(x)[i]))
             }}
My_function(all.data)
```

Comment: This is great. But what if the column is an integer and not numeric? What do I add to the code to deal with both numeric and integer variables?

Answer (score 1):

We can try `grep` to find the numeric/integer column and to filter those columns.

```
Subdat <- all.data[,!apply(all.data, 2, function(x) any(grepl("[A-Za-z]", x)))]
```

If we look at the output, it is still `character` class.  So, convert those columns to `numeric`

```
`dim<-`(as.numeric(Subdat), dim(Subdat))
```

---

However, it is not good to create a `matrix` with mixed column classes.  Even if there is a single non-numeric element, the whole `matrix` will be converted to `character` class.  It is better to create a `data.frame` or `list` (in case the lengths are also different) which can accommodate different classes and it is easier to filter out the columns.

Comment: Thanks but this is not working. Is there a specific line/place where I should insert the code?

Comment: @DarrinThomas  I would say the `all.data <- matrix(V1, V2, V3)` will not work.  Please check that again.  I guess you are doing `all.data <- cbind(V1, V2, V3)`